# Wordpress FSE: Remove body_class from body tag

Tags: wordpress

I am using Wordpress FSE with a custom theme.

How can I remove the body_class / the classes, which are automatically generated from the body tag?

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question and from my understanding, you want to remove the body tag classes. For this Wordpress provides a filter hook "body_class".

```js
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpwebguider_remove_body_class', 10, 1 );

function wpwebguider_remove_body_class( $classes ) {
  // empty the $classes array
  $classes = array();
  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this is not working. FYI: I am using Wordpress 6.3. with FSE.